# How to mock a Django model object (along with its methods)?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-3.5

I'm trying to mock a chained Django model object in the following dummy method,

```
# utils.py
def foo_something_exist():
   if Foo.objects.get(a='something').exist():
      return 'exist'



# test.py
import unittest.mock import patch

import utils

.
.
.
@patch('utils.Foo')
def test_foo_something_exist_returns_none(self, mock_foo):
   mock_foo.objects.get.exists.return_value = False
   self.assertIsNone(utils.foo_something_exist()) 
.
.
.
```

`test_foo_something_exist()` fails the test. I discovered that `Foo.objects.get(a='something').exist()` in utils.py was a MagicMock object (`<MagicMock name='Member.objects.get().exists()' id='xxxxxx'>`) instead of `False`, which contributed to the failure of this test function. And yes, I've also tried `mock_foo.objects.return_value.get.return_value.exists.return_value = False`, which was mentioned in a post. Pointers/hints for correctly mocking a model object (with its chained methods) is appreciate.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Don't patch the model itself but model.objects and then mock every part of the chain:

```
@patch('utils.Foo.objects')
def test_foo_something_exist_returns_none(self, mock_foo):
    # just to show how to do it with longer chains
    # mock_foo.filter.return_value = mock_foo
    # mock_foo.exclude.return_value = mock_foo            
    mock_foo.get.return_value = mock_foo
    mock_foo.exists.return_value = False

    self.assertIsNone(utils.foo_something_exist())
```

This also work's with `.filter()`, `.exclude()` and other model operations. I also find [Model Mommy](http://model-mommy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) really helpful when testing Django models.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May I know what does `mock_foo.get.return_value = mock_foo` do?

Comment: it uses the patched object as return value of every chained method call. So you end up with a patched object that has the methods and they all return the same patched object. This way it also doesn't matter in which order you chain the method calls.